# Maximum total sum of non-overlapping intervals with total weight W

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given a sequence `S` of `N` integers and a positive integer `W`, find a set of non-overlapping intervals such that their total weight is exactly W and their total sum is maximized.

```
For a chosen interval [i,j]:

 - Weight([i,j]) = j-i+1 
 - Sum([i,j]) = S[i+1] + S[i+2] + ... + S[j].
```

Example

```
S = (12, 9, 1, 2, 8, -1), W = 4  

Choose [1,2] and [4,5] with total_sum = Sum([1,2]) + Sum([4,5]) = 9 + 8 = 17

(12 9 _ 2 8 _)
```

This problem sounds a bit like the knapsack problem and weighted interval scheduling, but I think this can be solved in a much simpler way.

My idea was to use dynamic-programming and let `P[i][k] be the maximum total sum of the first i elements, using only k elements` and the answer would be `P[N][W]`, but I couldn't come up with a relation between the subproblems.

Comment: Despite the wording in terms of "intervals", the weight function doesn't depend on the "interval structure" at all, since for any way of splitting up some interval [i, j] into subintervals (including treating each of the j-i+1 elements as a separate length-1 interval), after summing their weights, the answer is the same.  The weight amounts to the total number of items selected, so this is actually a special case of the knapsack problem in which every item has weight 1.

Answer (score 1):

If you work from left to right you can summarize an answer so far by stating:

1) Its weight

2) The right end of the rightmost interval in that answer

3) The sum of the elements in its intervals

So I think you can solve this with a dynamic program run left to right if, at each stage, for each possible combination of right end of rightmost interval and total weight, you keep track of the answer with largest sum.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
  f[i][j]= MAX( f[i-1][j] , f[i-T][j-Weight[i-T,i]]+Sum[i-T,i] );
```

And then you get the answer in `f[N][W]`. I'm pretty sure there should be some way to optimize this `O(N^2W)` solution to a better one. But since you didn't ask for a faster one...